# How does a cpumask affect scheduling of other processes in the linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, affinity

I'm using a linux 2.6.x kernel on my machine which has ubuntu installed (Ubuntu is just mentioned in case this changes anything). The kernel runs on a machine that has 8 cores. The machine also runs openvz but I don't think this does change the context of the question.

I have a software installed that allows only the usage of two CPUs and it sets a hard CPU affinity on the first both CPUs (cpumask 3). I'm asking myself how the scheduling of the other processes is affected by this. I think I read something about it but I assume for now that processes are likely to be attached to the first CPUs. And the kernel tries to keep the processes on the same CPU always to avoid cache invalidation.

On the machine there are quite a few processes running. How does the kernel handle this situation? Can it be the hard CPU affinity proceses are running slower because they are affected while being bound to a crowded zone? How does the kernel care about the hard affinity.

Comment: I think, hardware interrupts may be locked on some first CPUs too. Also, if you has NUMA, there is an effort of kernel to keep processes and their data close. But if there is some software which locked to 1&2 CPUs (and both CPUs are used actively), then more likely that other software will be planned on cores 3-8, they have less load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What will happen in the long run is that the load balancing code of the scheduler will move more of the unbound tasks to the rest of the CPUs to account for this task being bound to the first two.

The way it works is that each task starts on the CPU where it was created and at the micro level the Linux task scheduler does scheduling decisions on each CPU without regard for the others. But then there is the more macro level process migration load balancing code that will step up and say: "the run queue (list of processes waiting to be scheduled) on this cpu is longer than that cpu, let's move some over to balance the loads".

Of course, since your specific task is bound to the first two cpus the load balance will pick other tasks to move - so your bound task will in the long run will "push out" enough of the other non bound tasks to the other cpus and balance will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about process creation? Are they created always in the same place and moved then. Or is the length of the task list evaluated at process creation time and the processes are created in the empty space?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge a new task (new thread in a multi-threaded program or a the first thread of a new process) are always created on the CPU where the creating thread (the one that called the clone system call) is running at the time. It might get moved shortly thereafter (or even midway via creating it) though.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. And this answers my question in detail. This way there wouldn't be a problem because as soon as processes are moved to another CPU they create sub processes on another CPU and do not affect anything that insist to run on the first ones (well, roughly).